# Dual boot to new install of 17.10 with w10 not working

Tags: dual-boot

I just bought a computer with W10 pre-installed (no software supplied).
I would like to keep W10 for ms office work.

The machine has 2 "hdds": a 240Gb SSD, and a 2Tb HHD.

I installed 17.10 from a "live usb".

When asked, I elected to have 17.10 installed along side of W10.

I chose the default installation disk (the larger one), and adjusted the size of the Ubuntu space to 150 mb.

(I could not figure out how to work with the manual disk installation screen, though I would have liked to put the boot, and perhaps the entire Ubuntu machine, on the SSD.)

After installation, I was directed to reboot.

My machine rebooted in W10.

I found and installed boot-repair. NoGo. 
The paste info from boot.repair is 26090895.

I tried reordering the boot devices, like I did to boot from the live-usb. NoGo.

(It isn't clear to me that the larger 2Tb drive shows up as a boot device in the setup screen. I selected the option of usb HDD.)

So, any suggestions as to how to fix this? I would be happy to blow away the currently allocated Ubuntu space and start over. It took about 10 minutes to install 17.10.

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: Boot-Repair posts a fully clickable link. Please post that so we can see your configuration. What brand/model system? What video card/chip? did you install in UEFI boot mode?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: @oldfred: WRT boot-repair info, I hope you mean:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/26090895/ .  I assume that will provide the needed configuration info? During Ubuntu installation, I did not see where a choice for UEFI boot mode was "made available". I know all other boot options on the motherboard startup screen are UEFI. Tim

Comment: Both Windows & Ubuntu are UEFI booting from the ESP - efi system partition on sda2. Your Ubuntu install is in sdb4. You also have nVidia and may need nomodeset until you install nVidia driver from repository. And you may need ppa to have newest drivers. What brand/model system? Can you directly boot Ubuntu from UEFI boot menu often f10 or f12, varies by brand. http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: @oldfred: I just realized that a comment I thought I added . . .  wasn't added. I tried changing the boot order, to no avail. (I change the boot order to run "live usb.) The system is a cyberpowerpc: GXiVR8140A, Intel i7-8700K, 16 Gb DDR4 2400, NVIDIA Geforce GTX 1080 8Gb. I just edited my original question, in an attempt to add files (specs, gparted screen shots), but copy/paste doesn't seem to work. May I ask: How would I go about getting files from my file system on the forum? Finally, my take from gparted is that a second boot partition (?) on the harddrive @ /dev/sdb3.

Comment: If a larger amount of info better to use pastebin site, like Boot-Repair does. You can copy & paste terminal output and then need to preserve formatting. Are you using nomodeset? Just about required until you install nVidia driver & you will need ppa for newest driver. https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers Do not really need gparted screen shots as Boot-Repair report shows all partitions and lots of details. If changed post new report in first post.

Comment: Is there a way to post files from my file system, so that people on Ask Ubuntu can open?

Comment: I just looked up nomodeset. I have no idea what the value is, or where to set it, in my situation.

Comment: Smaller data you can just copy & paste, just be sure to maintain formatting. At grub menu you can use e for edit, scroll to linux line and replace quiet splash with nomodeset.
How to set NOMODESET and other kernel boot options in grub2 - both BIOS liveCD & grub first boot ( also UEFI with grub) 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2 & 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132
How to add boot parameters,  grub menu after install (also grub when UEFI)
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters

Comment: I put a  pdf of the computer description on Filebin, as an experiment. (I just found the site.) https://filebin.ca/3jNW10d9IO8W

Comment: For just standard computer specs, you can just post link to vendor's site with model number. Various Linux commands give more detail, but some are not in standard distribution & must be added after install or into live installer. Very new computer will need newest kernel or even adding newer just released kernel not yet in standard distribution. And you will need ppa to add newest nVidia driver as per link above.

Comment: @oldfred: I don't make it to a grub screen: I am not getting there. Perhaps I should remove the partitions created during my install, and start again? Then I would need to know how to find out which partitions those are.   BTW: Filebin (above url) holds a pdf of the specs on my computer.

Comment: Your pastebin shows the details of your partitions. What brand/model system? Can you select f10 or f12 (check manual) and choose the Ubuntu entry? Or a  hard drive entry? You have UEFI system, and UEFI boot installs. But somehow have a BIOS Windows boot loader in sdb. Do not turn on or boot  live installers in BIOS boot mode. If you really want to reinstall, only use Something Else.

Comment: @oldfred: The system is a cyberpowerpc; with other details at the "above" filebin link. I get to the setup screen using the delete key. I have tried all reasonable startup devices, to no avail. I do plan to use "Something Else". Thank you for the pointer. I would have uninstalled the new install of Ubuntu immediately, except I don't know how to make sure the boot partitions are cleaned. Does approaching uninstall from the Windows side, rather than using live usb, seem reasonable - to deal with fixing the boot partitions?

Comment: Generally only use Windows tools for Windows & Linux tools for Linux. Or better to use gparted. But if reinstalling into the same partition, you just need to check the format box and everything is erased. If separate /home you never check the format as you want same data saved. But either way, you want full backups of Windows & all your data. In UEFI/BIOS you should be able to set boot order and with some highter numbered f key like f10 or f12, some like HP use esp f9 so check your manual and you should get the UEFI boot menu. Same as when selecting UEFI boot of flash drive.

Comment: @oldfred: Just letting you know that reading up, and using Something Else, led me to a successful dual boot - though it took a couple of restarts to have grub come up, and that was/is "scary". Thank you.

Comment: What ever works. :)